# android - read arabic from local json file

Tags: android, json, android-json

please someone help me , i try read arabic string from json file

the code i use it , i try read multi-lines of arabic language

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("horo_scop.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF_8");

            System.out.println("horo json file " + json);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

it print arabic like that "????? ???"

how can i fix it

Comment: What encoding is used when saving the horo_scop.txt file? Assuming that file contains the correct text you need to read it using the same encoding.

Comment: Try setting the text on TextView instead of SysOut. And also for logging use Log.* classes. Quit use of SysOut and other java console streams.

Comment: i dont encode when i save file , it enocde when i read it
i do print it in textview

Comment: @user3240583 : In order to store arabic characters a text file must use some form of encoding - a basic "plain text" file will only support ASCII characters. Whatever you're using to save it must be using one of the character-set encodings such as Unicode etc. It's most likely that whatever it's saved in, is not the same encoding as the one you're using to read it back.

Comment: what's android ver you support?